# How i could to make SSl Connection server using username, password by python?

Tags: python, ssl, server

Hello I would ask if i could do connection to extract some data from Tool Server.

so i making this code but i need to modify it to open this tool with username and password and extract data from My tool server.

```
import socket
import ssl

HOST, PORT = '10.74.159.82', 31039

def handle(conn):
    conn.write(b'GET  /  HTTP/1.1\n')
    print(conn.recv() . decode())

def main():
    sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET) 
    context = ssl.create_default_context(ssl.Purpose.SERVER_AUTH)
    conn = context.wrap_socket(sock, server_hostname=HOST)
    try:
        conn.connect((HOST, PORT))
        handle(conn)
    finally:
        conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

RESULT

```
       !! C:\Users\Admin\.PyCharmCE2018.1\config\venv\Scripts\python.exe!! C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/codestyles/Under_Building.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/codestyles/Under_Building.py", line 22, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:/Users/Admin/.PyCharmCE2018.1/config/codestyles/Under_Building.py", line 16, in main
    conn.connect((HOST, PORT))
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1141, in connect
    self._real_connect(addr, False)
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1132, in _real_connect
    self.do_handshake()
  File "C:\Users\Admin\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\ssl.py", line 1108, in do_handshake
    self._sslobj.do_handshake()
ssl.SSLCertVerificationError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: self signed certificate in certificate chain (_ssl.c:1045)
Process finished with exit code 1
```

I'm Beginner so i need to learn and supporting

Comment: That code isn't valid Python. I suggest you fix it / clean up the formatting to help people read and understand your question

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to see exactly, but it seems the server you're connecting to (on https://10.74.159.82:31039) is using a [self-signed certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Self-signed_certificate) (or its CA is, perhaps).

It's perhaps better to create or buy a proper (non-self-signed) certificate, but assuming this is a test server this is fine.

So with what you have, your best bet is to allow self-signed certs in your SSL Context (and also, not to check the hostname - that will probably fail too as you're using an IP address):

```
context = ssl.create_default_context()
context.check_hostname=False
context.verify_mode=ssl.CERT_NONE
# etc...
```